# How to display data from relationships in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have relationships in laravel and when I have nothing in table I got undefined offset 0. So I did something like this:

```
Sex: @if($user->user_data[0]->sex == 0) <br />@else {{$user->user_data[0]->sex}}<br /> @endif
```

Here is controller and model:

Model:

```
public function getUserById($id)
    {

        $user = User::with('user_data', 'comments')->where('id',$id)->first();

        return $user;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function getUser($id) 
{
    $user = $this->model->getUserById($id);

    return view('user.user', compact('user'));
}
```

how I can do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@if(isset($user->user_data[0]))
{{ $user->user_data[0]->sex }}
@else
Unknown
@endif
```

**Option 2**

```
{{$user->user_data[0] or 'Unknown'}}
```

Comment: It's the same like my but with unknown. I want this ''

Comment: I mean that if i could do better that if's or get data from relationship to not use user_data[0]

Comment: You can define it in the controller

Comment: What do you mean?